# Why is the angle of the mouse and the player changing when the player is outside of the camera deadzone?

Tags: lua, game-development, love2d

[This a camera module](https://github.com/a327ex/STALKER-X) designed in Lua for use in the Love2D framework. When you set up the camera, it takes a 'deadzone' where, when the followed object is within this 'deadzone', the camera doesn't move. The 'deadzone' is shown by the green corners around the centre of the screen.

[Here is what it looks like in my game when I'm just moving around.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcYA7.gif)

When the player character is within the deadzone, shooting works as expected. I am relatively novice at the Lua programming language, but in previous projects I've found that this code works and makes sense for finding the direction for a bullet, where `mx` and `my` are the mouse coordinates, and `px` and `py` are the player coordinates.

```
direction = math.atan((my-py)/(mx-px))
if px > x then direction = direction + math.pi end
```

[When I'm within the deadzone and shooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL9IQ.gif)

But as the player moves outside of the deadzone and shoots at the same time, it adds a seemingly random angle to the direction.

[Moving and shooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbLdY.gif)

I have no idea what is going on. I've been using this code for finding `mx` and `my`:

```
mx, my = love.mouse.getPosition()
mx = (x-love.graphics.getWidth()/2)/window.scale+camera.x
my = (y-love.graphics.getHeight()/2)/window.scale+camera.y
```

Which follows the mouse perfectly.

[Showing that it is finding the correct mouse position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh3h8.gif)

So I have no idea what is going on, because I presume `px` and `py` are correct because if they weren't, it would be drawing them to the wrong location.

Hopefully this all makes sense and I'm happy to clarify anything that isn't clear or exhibit any more code.

Comment: Is `mx` updated before `direction`? And both camera and player either before or after the aiming? It looks like the aim is lagging a single frame behind, which can happen if you update direction, camera and player in the wrong order.

Comment: first the camera is updated, then the player, then the aiming. Is that in the right order?

Comment: Not sure, and I'm mainly guessing here, I can't really wrap my mind around this rn. Take a look at https://love2d.org/wiki/love.run and consider, that fetching the mouse position is not up to date. Not sure if this affects the behavior significantly. Do you have your project on GitHub or similar?

Comment: I didn't add the github to the question because it's incredibly messy and might be tedious to decipher. But I'm guessing the problem stems from the shoot() function in game.lua and the modified love.run() in main.lua. From what I can gather, the order of player movement, `mx` and the camera doesn't seem to effect the aim... https://github.com/Scalzo-OS/arena-2

Comment: Ok I think I found most of the issues: call `camera:follow` before `camera:update` to avoid this single frame lag between changing direction. Move the two lines after the player movement to avoid another frame loss. (both are unrelated to the actual issues, I just noticed a lot of jumping around) Now the movement feels more smooth. I decreased the bullet speed and verified their movemend, they are perfectly aligned. Of course it will look like its off, since bullets move absolute and not relative to the player, but thats fine if its a design choice.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful! So, if my understanding is right, the angle is not off, it's just the position of the mouse relative to the player is changing due to the fact that the player is moving, thus the camera is moving with it?

Comment: Yes! If you shoot while moving, then stand still, you can see how the bullet moves correctly. Maybe slow down the bullet so its easier to see.